# Global GTK+ hotkey

Tags: gtk

Ideally, I'd like to bind a hotkey across all apps using gtk.

I have Ctrl+Shift+p bound to paste from the selection buffer in urxvt, which generally means I can do everything without moving my hands from the keyboard (vim is X buffer aware, and I have a tmux hook to place copied text into that buffer) however, when I go to firefox et al, I have to move my hand to the mouse to middle click.

Is it possible to bind global behaviour like this in the context of the gtk textentry widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ 2 allows customization of keyboard bindings (among other things) via `gtkrc` files, such as `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. (There does not seem to be *any* equivalent for GTK+ 3 programs.)

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to paste from the *PRIMARY* selection, only from *CLIPBOARD* selection (which already has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> assigned by default, so this customization will be useless):

```
binding "custom-text-entry"
{
    bind "<ctrl><shift>p" { "paste-clipboard" () }
}
class "GtkEntry" binding "custom-text-entry"
```

However, real GTK+ programs already have a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> for pasting from the *PRIMARY* selection, while Firefox is *not* pure GTK+ – many controls it uses are reimplemented in Firefox itself. You might need to [edit some internal files](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_(Firefox)#Any_OS.2C_without_GTK) to change its shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks! I realised that firefox may be tricky but I use a stack of GTK apps so just having it work in them is a lot better than nothing!